# AWS Glue - InvalidInputException (status: 400): Unable to parse the schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, jsonschema

AWS Glue - InvalidInputException (status: 400): Unable to parse the schema

While importing or applying the schema(json schema draft-07 was used) for a table in AWS Glue I received the noninformative error:

```
InvalidInputException (status: 400): Unable to parse the schema
{ "message": "Unable to parse the schema", "code": "InvalidInputException", "time": "2023-06-22T15:21:40.231Z", "requestId": "de0a78cc-9aee-4174-a007-7beab25fa3be", "statusCode": 400, "retryable": false }
```

I was using the schema that passes validation on every online schema validator that I found, and it works as expected

Where can I see the verbose error messages?

Comment: I'm sorry, but is there a question in here?  SO does have an "answer your own question" option, but it still involves asking a question, then separately providing an answer below.

Comment: thanks, I've created a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't found a place where the verbose errors are stored, but here is how I solved the issue:
I started to add properties one by one before realizing that the error was caused by one of the properties that did not have a type, and the string was not inferred in AWS Glue automatically.

Comment: Which property was it?